# Encoding issue for message feed title

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed, internationalization

[Message feeds block](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22462/stack-overflow--/?tab=feeds) has encoding issue with non-Latin title:

> [image: questions]

Text inside the circle should be rendered as `Последние вопросы - Stack Overflow на русском Meta`, as you could see after clicking on link.

Comment: i'm pretty sure again something wrong with encoding in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fixed. As Grundy correctly guessed, we were using ANSI storage for the name rather than unicode. I have updated the database schema and manually set the name for this feed (although IIRC we update the name periodically anyway, when we execute the feed).